# Adding a picture from an upload button to your home page

Tags: php

The title pretty much sums it up. Basically, I have a upload button on a separate page, and I want the image that gets uploaded placed in a specific spot on the home page. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: This is done using PHP. Why are you tagging this with CSS and HTML?

Comment: Best way? Save it on server, get it from server.

Comment: BEFORE YOU ANSWER, DON'T! THE OP OBVIOUSLY HAS DONE NO RESEARCH!

Comment: @TommyCoffee it could also have some AJAX...

Comment: hmm, to me it seems the OP really has no idea where to start. Typing this in Google won't give you any results, so a little bit of pointing him in the right direction wouldn't do any harm

Comment: Ok, well... typing this on Google in future will for result give a link to this page :)

Comment: @Kenneth searching for "html5 image upload" brings up no relevant results?  Interesting...

Comment: @Cole Johnson You, obviously, don't know what I have and haven't done. I have researched, and came up with no good way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a server-side technology to accept the image.

On the server-side you will need to save the image somewhere.

Then, either through AJAX or by reloading the page, you need to embed an img-tag pointing at the image on the server

Comment: You can update your answer with more details (about PHP, Ruby, MySQL, some links to tutorials etc)

Comment: Well, in this case, I'd like the OP to do some more research on his behalf, see what technology he wants to use and try out some things. After that, we'll be glad to help him out with whatever technique he wishes to use